# Seamless Page Changing with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to make my website pages load seamlessly. If you click a page on some of the links below you will see what I'm talking about.

http://www.ultranoir.com/

http://www.itsmassive.com/

when you click on the link it loads the information and /#!/ is added to the url.  How do I add this feature so my pages load the same way? Is there a tutorial anywhere?

Comment: Check out [pjax](http://pjax.heroku.com/) or [History.js](https://github.com/balupton/History.js/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is called a `hashchange` event.  You can change the value after the `#!` without reloading the page, then you can use AJAX to load the info you want.  If you're using a new browser that supports HTML5, then you can use `History.pushState` to change the url bar in a similar way.

Basically, you add an event to the links, change the URL (using `location.hash` or `pushState`), and then you can you load the data via AJAX.

[Here](http://blog.dcoinc.net/?p=313) is a decent example of `location.hash`, [and here's](http://blog.dcoinc.net/?p=398) one for `pushState`.

For a good cross-browser solution, I suggest [History.js](https://github.com/balupton/History.js/).

If you want to use History.js, after adding the scripts to your page, you need to add a bit of JavaScript too.

```
$('a.hash').click(function(e){  // For all links with the class "hash"
   e.preventDefault();  // Don't follow link
   History.pushState(null, '', this.href);  // Change the current URL (notice the capital "H" in "History")
   $('#content').slideUp('slow', function(){  // Animate it sliding up
       var $this = $(this);
       $this.load(this.href, function(){  // Use AJAX to load the page (or do whatever)
          $this.slideUp('slow');  // Slide back down
       });
});
```

Comment: history.js does seem like the best option after taking a look at it.  I came across this https://gist.github.com/854622 from the author of history.js but a little confused on how to implement.. I included the scripts, but not sure if theres any more that I need to do..

Comment: @JoeBobby: After adding the scripts, you need to add some JavaScript to the page to have it use `History.js`.  I'll add an example to my answer.

Comment: I places this in my head and added .hash to the navigation links but im not sure if its working or not.. how can i tell?

Comment: @JoeBobby: Open up a JavaScript console (like FireBug, or Chrome's built-in one) and see if the whole page refreshes, or if an AJAX call is fired.  You can also add some animation (like `slideUp` and `slideDown`) to see that it's working.

Comment: @JoeBobby: This is untested, and is just something I quickly threw together. :-P

Comment: it seems ot be working because it loads the contents of my #content div but everything else disappears.. like header, footer, etc.. is there something i might of done wrong?

Comment: @JoeBobby: You're gonna have to make sure it only replaces the data you want.  You can add a selector to `load` to have it use only that data (`$this.load(this.href+' #content')`).  You should also make sure `#content` is the right selector you want to replace.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ddwxb/ here is how i have it set up.. is there anythin i did incorrectly?