# Fade in and out page transition

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, transition

I'm looking for a way to fade pages in and out similar to the below URL while keeping each page as separate pages. I've tried using jQuery to accomplish this but keep getting a gap of time in between transitions while the page loads.  Does anyone know any way of accomplishing this while keeping the page separate.  My site is in Wordpress.

http://spring.tnvacation.com/#!/winning

Comment: I have only thing I have tried far so fading the page out when an anchor tag is clicked and fading the page in on page load with jQuery.  Are Ajax sites like this compatible with SEO?

Comment: Depends on what your Ajax is doing. Just intercepting click and load actual href in place (SEO friendly). Or completely recreating the navigation (not SEO friendly).

Comment: Interesting...I'll have to check this out.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: I found another same SO question with different site example and answer explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8495459/772402.

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to look at the history api to dynamically change browser history and load content using Ajax. [Davis.js](http://davisjs.com/) would be a good start.

Comment: Thank for the quick response! I have thought about using Ajax but I wasn't to sure it would be good for seo.  The only things that I have tried so far is fading the page out when an anchor tag is clicked and fading the page in on page load with jQuery.  I will have to look more into the Ajax solution if it is compatible with seo.