# jQuery CSS Page Transition

Tags: jquery, css, transition, pageload

I've been testing out page transitions using jQuery and CSS transitions. What I'm trying to achieve is that the loading between pages is 'seamless' i.e. the page doesn't flicker. (Examples of what I'm trying to achieve: https://www.dropbox.com/guide, http://www.rezo-zero.com/en/)

One of the most common examples on the web is the following article on Codrops: http://tympanus.net/Development/PageTransitions/. Even though it's a great effect the example shown here only cycles through elements on the same page and not **redirect to another page**.

Apart from Codrops I've also had a look at the smoothState.js (http://css-tricks.com/add-page-transitions-css-smoothstate-js/) plugin which although the demo looks great I have not been able to achieve the same results with the tests I've made. Exiting animation wasn't being triggered plus pages seemed to take ages to load at times. Maybe I was doing something wrong but the plugin doesn't seem to be stable enough at the moment.

After a bit more research I found this question on stackoverflow: [Seamless Page Changing with AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495324/seamless-page-changing-with-ajax) and managed to create the effect I wanted. Example of this can be seen here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18543481/historyjs-page-transition/test.html.

The simple test I have here is that once the full screen loading is visible the content slides up, loads to the other page and the content slides down. (Note that it's a simple test for now and not everything is in place, namely the back button but I know that the issue is easily fixed).

**What I'd like to ask is whether the approach I'm using is correct or whether there's a better way to tackle this?**

Finally I'd like to add that I've also read that something like this could also be achieved with Angular.JS, not sure if it's viable solution as I've never used Angular.JS before.

Comment: You need to consider if the user wants to go "back" or start over.  Transitions like this can make people upset when they want to follow their own navigation.  At a minimum, you should have a way to get to the start of navigation on the home page.

Comment: Like I mentioned in my question the test I've made is simple and I know that the 'back' functionality should always be available. My question isn't regarding the 'back' functionality as I do know how that issue can be tackled. All I'm asking is whether the approach I'm using to create a page transition is the best way.

Comment: The 'better way' to tackle it is (arguably) to not tackle it. You're essentially trying to change the way default page loading works. That's not to say it's a bad idea. Maybe it is worth the effort. But just realize you're breaking the 'default' behavior of how one navigates between pages. As long as you keep that in mind and accommodate browser navigation, bookmarking, and the like this might be just fine.

Comment: I don't disagree with your comments here regarding making sure all browser functionality still works, but I don't think AJAX page loading is something that should be in any way discouraged, as the tone of your comment suggests. It's a challenge to do well, but it's a commonly implemented feature and I feel can lead to a dramatically increased user experience.

Comment: As I did mention I do know that the basic browser functionality should be there. The point of what I'm trying to achieve is to make the website more 'flowing' and 'seamless' which should lead to a better user experience. @DA. Please do have a look at the examples I've listed in my question. Dropbox's guide, is particularly a great example to follow and I don't think there's anything wrong with the navigation.

Comment: @SimonRobb yes and no. I've seen it go both ways. It *can* lead to a better user experience. It can also make for a more frustrating user experience. Hence my comments. I wasn't trying to discourage it, but emphasize that if it's done, make sure it's done right.

Comment: I agree, the dropbox example is very nice. It's all going to be in the details!

Comment: @DA. Sure thing, agreed!

Answer (score 1):

AngularJS certainly makes this an easy task - since AJAX page load is baked in to the framework by default, you simply need to attach the CSS animation styles to the appropriate hooks which Angular provides. Here's a good reference for Angular animation at [yearofmoo.com](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/08/remastered-animation-in-angularjs-1-2.html).

However, it's not necessary to use Angular - in fact I'd suggest it's a little heavy if all you want is page transitions. Your approach sounds correct to me:

- Fetch new content
- When successfully fetched, add the content off-screen, or whatever works for the effect you're going for
- Apply a class to the body to indicate the animation to take place
- Wait for the animation attached to the class to complete using a timeout
- Remove the old off-screen content, and the animation class from the body

There's libraries out there that might help you out, but it sounds like you're doing okay on your own!

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I'll just try to see where my implementation takes me. I'm just trying a few things out maybe I'll manage to create some cool effects :)

Comment: No worries! [Here's some inspiration](http://tympanus.net/Development/PageTransitions/) :)

Comment: Been looking at that for ages haha :) Thanks anyway :)